# How to detect mobile devices Multiple Select?

Tags: javascript, css, browser-detection

I want to apply different style if my Multiple select is shown on a mobile device as an iPhone or Android, because it looks ugly. The question is how to detect it:

- cannot use media-query for width, cause that may also include desktop browsers
- cannot rely on pixel density, cause some tablets also have density>1
- not sure if it is enough to just [detect mobile browser](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

I do not want a (jQuery) replacement for `<select multiple>`, just want to be sure I'm styling one-line-ugly-mobile-ui (and not a desktop version). I do not care if solution is html only, Javascript, css or combination of all.

Comment: Why not use a combination? - detect `user-agent` string, and see if the width is below what you consider mobile.

Comment: Im not sure the width has anything with mobile presentation of multiple-select, also not sure if user-agent is enough, that's why I asked this question. I hope someone had same problem and solved it. (At the end I shall test it on Android, iPhone and Windows phone quickly, just thinking this may be a good Q/A).

Comment: I don't think I understood you correctly. Is your question simply about detecting mobile browsers? What's so special about Multiple select that makes it hard to detect and style on mobile?

Comment: Well, do all mobile browsers show one-line multiple-select? Guess the way we detect 'mobile' browsers is also important. Simply I am not sure if regex on user-agent string is enough to be sure the multiple-select is mobile-like. There may be a way to check if options are visible or in several lines, or something else, some better way. Maybe it has other events attached?